# Exchange of encrypted files through a server

Tags: encryption, java, server

I have a thing to do, that basically bases on a server that is honest but curious. Therefore I want the server to have the public key for encryption and it will encrypt files during the process of upload, and different users will be able to download their respective files and decrypt them using their private keys.

Thing is, I do not know where to start. I'm a student and it's my project, but I lack background. What I'm asking for is some directions and materials to help me learn to do it. I know already how to do keypair generation in Java, but no idea how to do the server.

Is this http://technojeeves.com/index.php/48-server-by-david-flanagan a good start? Where do I go from here?

Comment: Do the users have their own keypairs already? Does the server have to generate those keys as part of the process?

Comment: This might fare better over at [prog](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/), but why do you want the server to do the encryption? it would be safer to have the client do the encryption prior to uploading (unless your server is doing something with the unencrypted data, in which case there isn't much point in encrypting it anymore..)

Comment: Users don't have their own keypairs, they are being generated in the process. I guess they way to go about it is to write an application that encrypts using a public key during pre-upload?

Answer (score 1):

So basically, the server will generate a key-pair for each user that signs up. It will give the user the private key, and keep the public key to encrypt anything that it receives for the user. When information is sent to the server (in plaintext) for the user to obtain, the server will encrypt the data with the public key, and when the information is downloaded, the user will decrypt the data.

A server is just a machine on a network that is providing a service (service, server... haha). Some services include file hosting (FTP servers for example), website hosting (for websites!), maybe voice servers to host common voice apps like ventrilo, mumble, teamspeak, etc. As far as what kind of server you'd need, that depends a lot on how you want to go about it.

If you are using java/javascript, you might consider using a web server of some kind, and writing some custom scripts to automatically encrypt any files uploaded through your interface. This isn't my forte either, but that's kind of what it looks like.